# Does AWS allow us to pre-process email for clients using SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'd like to pre-process my clients email via AWS SES, but I'm not sure Amazon allows for this per their policy and/or has a domain limitation. I see a rule-set for my SES engine and I'm able to manage multiple domain names, but these are my own. If I wanted to managed 100 or 200 domain names, would AWS SES allow me to do this?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? What do you mean by "manage my clients email via AWS SES"? Amazon Simple Email Service is for sending bulk **outbound** mail. It is not an email system like Gmail. You might be more interested in using [Amazon WorkMail - Managed Email for Business](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/).

Comment: I will preprocess a client's email and then forward to them.

Answer (score 1):

If your clients grant you permission to manage their email on their behalf, it's not up to Amazon to tell you if you can or cannot. Remember, they are providing Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS).

As far as if it's possible technically, you'll have to either create your own e-mail client that integrates with SES or use Amazon WorkMail.

Comment: I want to use SES as a preprocess and then forward the email.

Comment: @CharlesSaag Use SES to trigger a Lamda function that both processes the e-mail and then forwards it to it's final destination.

Comment: I do that now; thanks for the update though. I'm asking if AWS will at some point prevent me from doing this if I get, say 1,000 users ... or 2,000 ... etc.

Comment: @CharlesSaag Nope! They'll just charge you more for the additional load. You'll never outscale Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

You can send any number of emails(based on your SES limits) and manage any number of domains as long as you comply with amazon policies. All they care about it quality of email response, if someone report spam and if your spam ration is high then your account might be at risk.

Comment: Yes, this is my concern. If I have 100 or 1,000 customers ... and one of them spams, would that shut down all of them?

Comment: Technically Yes